# How can i make three tables relationships in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I want to create dynamice mega menu but i'm getting error when i'm making  tables relationship. Please let me know how can i make relationship.

**Table structure Below:-**

1) categories

**id integer**

**category varchar**

2) subcategories

**id integer**

**subcategory varchar**

**category_id integer**

3) parentcategories

**id integer**

**parentname varchar**

**subcategory_id integer**

**Models**

Categories.php

```
protected $table = "categories";
public function sub(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Subcategories::class,Parentcategories::class,'subcategory_id','category_id');
}
```

Subcategories.php

```
protected $table = "subcategories";
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
}
```

Parentcategories.php

```
protected $table = "parentcategories";
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategories');
}
```

PagesController.php

```
public function index(){
    $categories = Categories::all();
    return view('pages.home')->with('categories',$categories);
}
```

blade template

```
      @foreach($categories as $category)
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {{ $category->category }} <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" 
          aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="mega-menu dropdown-menu">
          @foreach($category->sub->take(20) as $subcategory)
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <h5>{{$subcategory->subcategory}} <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h5>
              <ul class="mega-list">
                <li><a href="#">parent categories comes here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </li>
      @endforeach
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want categories and subcategories hierarchy table?

Comment: i want categories,subcategoires and parentcategories hierarchy table

Comment: You mean three level, on top comes parent categories then comes categories and then comes sub categories?

Comment: on top comes categories then comes subcategories and then comes parentcategories

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your table are hierarchy is in simillar fashion, I guess this can be done with single table. Create a table named `categories` and follow the below table structure:

[image: navigation table]

Now create a model **Category.php**: something like this:

```
<?php

class Category extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function parent() {

        return $this->hasOne('category', 'id', 'parent_id');

    }

    public function children() {

        return $this->hasMany('category', 'parent_id', 'id');

    }  

    public static function tree() {

        return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 4, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();

    }

}
```

Now in your controller suppose **HomeController.php** write:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = "layouts.main";

    public function showWelcome()
    {

        $items = Category::tree();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('layouts.home.index')->withItems($items);

    }

}
```

And in views suppose **index.blade.php** you can simply pass like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <li>{{ $item->title }}
            @foreach($item['children'] as $child)
            <li>{{ $child->title }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This works for n-number for hierarchy, more efficient and a single table categories, hope this helps